# Sessions wont stay after page refresh

Tags: php, session

**Problem is solved, the problem was that the sessions where hijacked deu an attack**

I just upgraded to a new php version and it seems like the sessions won't work anymore, they register fine but after a page reload they don't work anymore, they're gone.

I've tried a lot of things, like session.save_path.

my PHP: PHP Version 5.4.32

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 123; //when i remove this line and i refresh the page, the session is gone
print_r($_SESSION); ?>
```

Here is my php info, the part for the sessions:

```
Session Support enabled

Registered save handlers    files user

Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary


Directive   Local Value Master Value

session.auto_start  Off Off

session.cache_expire    180 180

session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache

session.cookie_domain   no value    no value

session.cookie_httponly Off Off

session.cookie_lifetime 0   0

session.cookie_path /   /

session.cookie_secure   Off Off

session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom

session.entropy_length  32  32

session.gc_divisor  1000    1000

session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440

session.gc_probability  1   1

session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5

session.hash_function   0   0

session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID

session.referer_check   no value    no value

session.save_handler    files   files

session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp

session.serialize_handler   php php

session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On

session.upload_progress.enabled On  On

session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%

session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1

session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS

session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_

session.use_cookies On  On

session.use_only_cookies    On  On

session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: Did you defined a writable path when you tried `session.save_path`?

Comment: it seems writable, when i change it to a different value in php it self it gives an error

Comment: What error? And how did you tried to change it?

Comment: I used this code, when i changed the directory in PHP.INI it would give me the error that is shown in the code `if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!'; 
}`

Comment: Which code? Does it show the `....is not writable for PHP...` message?

Comment: no it doesnt show that, so it should be writable

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini provide directory where to store session files and make sure they are readable by servers user.

```
sessions.save_path = "/path/to/your/folder"
```

Otherwise, you can use directly in php file

```
ini_set(session.save_path, '/path/to/your/folder')
```